# In Google Sheets is there a way to see an average value for a given timestamp

Tags: google-sheets

Say I'm logging the pH of something on an hourly basis and I want to know the average pH of that something at 6am vs 6pm is, how could I easily queue up that data in Google Sheets?

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks but I just realized this can be achieved with the AVERAGEIF function. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en

Comment: You are correct, one does not tend to know what they are missing if they don't know what they are missing. ;) So care to elaborate on QUERY and FILTER?